# Audio tearing, Freeze

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, sound-card, surround-sound

I'm running windows 7 64 bit. I've been getting audio tearing that lasts for about a second and is accompanied by a short freeze of the computer. It's really irritating, especially during games, or films or music. Some forum users suggest it's an IRQ conflict. These problems have been happening ever since I got a 7.1 headset.

Comment: The specific make and model of your headset would be useful.

Comment: The headset is a turtlebeach earforce z6

Comment: Check for updated drivers of the headset (assuming it's USB) and any sound cards (and video cards, if you use HDMI audio) in your system.

Comment: I've installed all the latest audio drivers, i'm going to try a BIOS update to see if it works. It's getting worse now, it's happening every few seconds and it makes a buzzing sound if that helps (coming from the speakers, not the tower)

Comment: The Z6 is not a USB device. It feeds and accepts analog signals to/from the sound card. To me that says the problem is with your sound card, not your headset. (The fact that your headset seems to cause the problem might be a coincidence, or you might be that using  the headset somehow uncovers a pre-existing bug in the sound card.) Look for IRQ conflicts between the sound card and other devices. Also consider replacing the sound card.